# Serializing list to JSON

Tags: python, django, json, serialization

I am sending information between client and Django server, and I would like to use JSON to this. I am sending simple information - list of strings. I tried using `django.core.serializers`, but when I did, I got

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_meta'
```

It seems this can be used only for Django objects. How can I serialize simple, Python objects?

Comment: Can you include a snippet of the actual code you actually used that produced this error?

Answer (score 105, accepted):

You can use pure Python to do it:

```
import json
list = [1, 2, (3, 4)] # Note that the 3rd element is a tuple (3, 4)
json.dumps(list) # '[1, 2, [3, 4]]'
```

Comment: Oh, it's a new module in 2.6, I don't have to use simplejson. Thanks a lot :-)

Comment: I simply cannot parse the dumped JSON file, because in this file, JSON_ARRAY is the direct child of another JSON_ARRAY.

Comment: How to get it back to list?

Answer (score 7):

If using Python 2.5, you may need to import `simplejson`:

```
try:
    import json
except ImportError:
    import simplejson as json
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, but then what do you do about the django objects? simple json tends to choke on them.

If the objects are individual model objects (not querysets, e.g.), I have occasionally stored the model object type and the pk, like so:

```
seralized_dict = simplejson.dumps(my_dict, 
                     default=lambda a: "[%s,%s]" % (str(type(a)), a.pk)
                     )
```

to de-serialize, you can reconstruct the object referenced with model.objects.get(). This doesn't help if you are interested in the object details at the type the dict is stored, but it's effective if all you need to know is which object was involved.