# How to convert a list of tuples in python 2.7 into JSON

Tags: mysql, json, python-2.7, list, tuples

My list of tuples is the result from a MySQL cursor.fetchall()

```
list= [(103L, 'keerthi', 3000L, 'chennai', 30L, 300L), (102L, 'ashwini', 2000L, 'chennai', 20L, 200L), (101L, 'uma', 1000L, 'chennai', 10L, 100L)]
```

I tried

```
json_string = json.dumps(list)
```

the output remains the same

[(103L, 'keerthi', 3000L, 'chennai', 30L, 300L), (102L, 'ashwini', 2000L, 'chennai', 20L, 200L), (101L, 'uma', 1000L, 'chennai', 10L, 100L)]

Comment: Why doesn't it help? What do you get instead of the result you expect?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2147701/serializing-list-to-json