# i want to Getting JSON values in python

Tags: sql-server, python-2.7

**Sorry. I can not explain the details because I am not fluent in English.**

I have a json document like this:

```
[
    {
        "id":"96103252",
        "pvname":"Bet365",
    }
]
```

My python code looks like this:

```
url_odds= cfg.oddsurl
oddsfeed = urllib2.urlopen(url_odds)
oddsjson = json.load(oddsfeed)
getjson = "{""data"":" + oddsjson + "}"

for sport in getjson["data"]:
   pv_id= validate(sport,"id")
   pv_name= validate(sport,"pv_name")
   sql= "INSERT INTO odds_sports(pv_id,pv_name) VALUES ('"
   sql= sql+ pv_id + "','"
   sql= sql+ pv_name + "')"
 cursor.execute(sql)
 conn.commit()
```

It sends this error

---

getjson = "{""data"":" + oddsjson + "}"

TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'list' objects

Comment: In order to do that you need to 'serialise' the list as a string first. Do these help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2147701/serializing-list-to-json Once you've serialised it you can concatenate it at your fourth line of code.

Comment: This says the same thing - use `dump` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26033239/list-of-objects-to-json-with-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that's a very simple syntax error. in this line:

```
getjson = "{""data"":" + oddsjson + "}"
```

oddsjson is an array of dicts, you probably want to iterate over each element in it and parse the right value hence:

```
for sport in oddsjson:
   pv_id = validate(sport.get("id"))
   pv_name = validate(sport.get("pvname"))
```

also,

and on another issue. hand-writing SQL queries with strings you generate on the go is an invitation for [troubles](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp) (especially when the query involves dynamic string generated by others). 
you better use some library like [sqlalchemy](https://www.sqlalchemy.org/) as a middleware to your database.