# Json handling of multiple list in python

Tags: python, json

Guys where I get multiple data each in a list from a database and append this to another list,so my data looks this way

```
data= [["a","b","c"],["1","2","3"]]
```

If I try to Json dump and load this data it give an error on the load side

```
data2 = str.encode(json.dumps(data))
st = bytes.decode(data2)
msg = json.loads(st)

raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s,err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

But this doesn't not happen where it is a single list

Comment: what's with all the str/bytes encoding/decoding? why not just `json.dumps(data)` and `json.loads` for the other way around?

Comment: Have you checked [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42710879/write-two-dimensional-list-to-json-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42710879/write-two-dimensional-list-to-json-file) ?

Comment: The code you have shown doesn't reproduce the problem.

Comment: This should answer the question pretty well - <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2147701/serializing-list-to-json>

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Serializing list to JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2147701/serializing-list-to-json)

Comment: My script isn't as straightforward as this,I wrote a simple code so my question ll be more efficient ,my script involves a threaded server and a client side,I ll probably edit it so it reflects the exact nature of my code

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you tried to achieve with all the str/bytes encoding/decoding, but this is as straightforward as

```
import json

data = [["a", "b", "c"], ["1", "2", "3"]]
json_str = json.dumps(data)
print(json_str)
# '[["a", "b", "c"], ["1", "2", "3"]]' <- a string
python_list = json.loads(json_str)
print(python_list)
# [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['1', '2', '3']] <- back to Python list
```

Comment: My script isn't as straightforward as this,I wrote a simple code so my question ll be more efficient ,my script involves a threaded server and a client side,I ll probably edit it so it reflects the exact nature of my code

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Solution for Json Dump and Load this data.

```
import json
data= [["a","b","c"],["1","2","3"]]

# print(data)

data2 = json.dumps(data)
print(data2)
msg = json.loads(data2)
print(msg)
```

Answer (score -1):

do you want json like this : {"data": [["a", "b", "c"], ["1", "2", "3"]]}

for this output this is the code

```
data= [["a","b","c"],["1","2","3"]]
import json
data_dict = {'data':data}
data2 = json.dumps(data_dict)
print(data2)
```

Comment: Thank you all guys I found a way around it,though it's not the best,turns out Json.load has issues with a list that contains too many list with  too many items in each,so after dumping, it cannot load it,I would like to know why json behaves like this,this has made my job more difficult,cos now where I have an sql TABLE  with 100columns.instead of using a sql statement (SELECT * FROM TABLE),in other to avoid json error I have to get it in smaller chunks (SELECT col1,col2,col3 FROM TABLE)